# Qual deve ser o uso correto da tag "bootstrap"?

Tags: debate, tags, tag-específica

> Antes de **tudo** quero que entenda que ao ler uma sugestão e negativar você deve comentar o motivo, pois isto é um debate e os votos aqui não influenciam no score, os votos aqui são apenas para tomar descisões, mas eu preciso saber o porque discorda da sugestão, negativar apenas não vai fazer eu ou a comunidade adivinhar o motivo de porque você discorda da sugestão.
>
> Teve alguns downvotes e eu realmente não sei o motivo do porque as sugestões foram consideradas ruins, então justifique, isso é um debate apenas.

### Antes de existir o http://getbootstrap.com (framework front-end)

O conceito *bootstrap* antes do famoso framework front-end denominado inicialmente "twitter bootstrap" era muito usado com a intenção de se referir a 3 situações em principal:

1. O processo de iniciar o computador ou sistema operacional (o que acho que dificilmente vai estar dentro do escopo do site, vai depender da duvida)
2. Bootstrapping também pode se referir ao desenvolvimento de ambientes de programação sucessivamente mais complexos, mais rápidos. O ambiente mais simples será, talvez, um editor de texto muito básico (por exemplo, ed) e um programa assembler. Usando essas ferramentas, pode-se escrever um editor de texto mais complexo, e um compilador para uma linguagem simples de nível superior e assim por diante, até que se possa ter uma IDE gráfica e uma linguagem de programação extremamente de alto nível.
3. Uma série de procedimentos correu quando um aplicativo é iniciado ou um pedido através da web é recebido (semelhante ao descrito no `2.`)

Muitas vezes também chamado apenas de `boot`, `booting` e `boot loader` (em português usamos eventualmente: iniciação ou carregador).

No entanto existe a questão das perguntas sobre [r](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), o termo bootstrap ou boot são muitos usados nelas devido a um pacote de mesmo nome(s) (http://www.r-bloggers.com/bootstrap-example/).

### Framework front-end

Inicialmente o http://getbootstrap.com usava o nome "twitter bootstrap" (ou twbootstrap) já que foi idealizado pelos mesmos, mas com a chegada da versão 3 o projeto passou a ser mais independente então o nome twitter foi removido, o framework alcançou tal popularidade que até outros conceitos como de compiladores ou outros pacotes como o do [r](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) ficam ofuscados.

### Entendendo

**Eu não acho** errado usar a tag [bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) para se referir:

- Framework front-end (getbootstrap.com)
- Ou o pacote do [r](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)
- Ou estatísticas (dentro das perguntas sobre `r` ou que use um conceito semelhante)
- ou algo que tenha haver com compiladores
- ou até mesmo o arranque do sistema (se tiver dentro do escopo)

Isto porque dentro do ambiente que cada desenvolvedor conhece ele vai assimilar que o uso dele está correto da tag, mas a questão é que as tags aqui no site devem ser especificas e este é o "dilema" que não sei aonde chegar pra determinar o que fazer com a tag.

Quero dizer, no nosso site a tag deve se referir apenas a um assunto pra obviamente evitar confusões.

### Vamos debater e dar sugestões?

Esta questão é pra discutir o melhor caminho a se tomar, por exemplo excluir tags? Adicionar novas tags? O que fazer? É um debate então por favor de sugestões:

- Responda com sugestões (pode ser uma ou mais respostas) podendo (ou não conter os assuntos a seguir):

  - Sugestões para tag que se refere ao http://getbootstrap.com e como resolver a tag já existente [bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap)
  - Sugestões para o pacote boot da linguagem [r](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)
  - Sugestões para outras variantes
- Positive se gostar de alguma sugestão de um colega
- Negative as sugestões que não gostar e de preferencia comente, **é importante** comentar o motivo da discordância, isto pode ser importante pra reforçar o motivo de discordar e de preferencia poste uma alternativa.

> não se preocupe aqui no meta os *downvotes* não afetam seus pontos eles são usados apenas com intuito de concordância e discordância

Answer (score 13):

### Proposta: alterar a tag bootstrap avisando no wiki que ela não deve ser usada, e criar tags especializadas para cada caso específico.

Da mesma forma que é feito com a `styles` do SOzão

> Link: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/styles/info
>
> DO NOT USE THIS TAG. This tag does not currently have a single, well-defined meaning. It is often used in place of, or in conjunction with, [css](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css). It is also used on questions about the appearance of user interfaces and questions about source code formatting.

ou seja

> NÃO USE ESSA TAG. Essa tag atualmente não tem um sentido único e bem definido. Normalmente é usada no lugar, ou em conjunto com [css](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css). Também é usada em questões sobre aparência de interfaces de usuário, e questões sobre formatação de código fonte.

Eu faria o mesmo com a nossa tag [bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) e complementaria o *wiki* dizendo:

> ... para o framework disponibilizado em getbootstrap.com, use a tag [bootstrap-ui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-ui), para a carga do sistema operacional, utilize a tag [boot](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boot), para estatísticas em R use [r-boot](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-boot) etc

Isso envolveria fazer o retagging de algumas perguntas, mas nada que a comunidade já não faça normalmente com outros assuntos.

<sub>Claro que "bootstrap-ui" foi um exemplo, precisa ver "nome e sobrenome" oficiais que definem o "treco" sem ambiguidade.</sub>

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfBiM.png

Comment: @Shog9 Obrigado. Se possível ajustar, atualmente seria algo assim:  "Se sua pergunta se refere ao framework web usado para grids, layout e estilização, use a tag "twitter-bootstrap" ou tag mais específica com número de versão. Se sua pergunta se refere à partida de um sistema, use a tag "bootstraping". Se está fazendo bootstrap para estatísticas em R ou outra linguagem, use a tag "estatística-bootstrap". - O wiki de tag atual está assim

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M40sP.png - não há tag "bootstraping"

Comment: @Shog9 creio que "boot" está ótimo. Eu havia feito o texto com base na conversa do chat, mas acabamos não achando os casos apropriados para retag. Grato novamente.

Answer (score 6):

> Queria colocar como comentário, mas ficou muito grande. Por isso deixei como resposta. Além disso, vou dar minha contribuição apenas no que se refere a R

Bootstrap quando aparece em R, se refere à uma técnica estatística que tem o mesmo nome e que faz parte de uma área chamada de reamostragem. Existem diversos pacotes do R que servem para fazer bootstrap, um deles é o `boot`. Acredito que quem posta perguntas com a tag `R` relacionadas a bootstrap não está necessariamente se referindo ao pacote `boot` e sim querendo resolver seu problema de bootstrap usando `R`, por isso não acredito que seja necessária uma tag `r-boot`.

Além disso, não acho que possa ser uma tag apenas relacionada ao `R`. Alguém poderia perguntar "como fazer boostrap em python?", por exemplo e seria uma pergunta válida.

Enfim, na minha opinião são tão poucas perguntas relacionadas a bootstrap/reamostragem que eu não vejo necessidade de existir uma tag específica. E na verdade, talvez seja um assunto muito mais relacionado a estatística do que a programação no caso das perguntas em R.

**Edit**

Respondendo as perguntas do comentário:

1)

Veja neste link aqui a definição de bootstrap para a estatística: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)
Portanto, não é um conceito atrelado à nenhuma linguagem de programação.

Deste modo assim como é possível fazer bootstrap em `R` usando pacote `boot`. É possível fazer bootstrap usando `python` usando [este módulo do SciPy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.bootstrap) por exemplo. É isso que eu quero dizer com fazer bootstrap com python.

2)

Veja que além do `boot` existe o pacote [`bootstrap`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bootstrap/index.html) para fazer a mesma coisa. [Neste link](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/bootstrap.htm) o autor primeiro faz uma função ele mesmo para fazer bootstrap e depois ensina a usar o pacote `boot`.

Concordo com você que sua última sugestão seria adequada. Inclusive veja que no SO original, nem existe uma tag específica se referindo a bootstrap em estatística... Apesar de existirem cerca de 2000 perguntas de R divididas entre bootstrap, bootstrapping e boot.

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição, parece que você entendeu a proposta aqui :) - Duas perguntas: 1: O que é bootstrap em python pra você? 2: Eu pesquisei bastante sobre bootstrap e R, não tenho conhecimento na linguagem, a unica coisa que achei foi o pacote "boot", poderia fornecer um exemplo? - Pra concluir de qualquer maneira acredito que a minha ultima sugestão resolveria ambos problemas a tag: `bootstrapping`, eles fizeram assim no StackOveflow em ingles :)

Comment: Respondi seu comentário na pergunta porque ficou longo de novo para um comentário.

Comment: +1 Agora ficou legal, a ideia era essa mesma dar detalhes do porque das coisas, assim ajuda a formar opiniões ;)  - Só um detalhe, o link que enviou usa a o termo `bootstrapping` e não `bootstrap` (tempo verbal diferente :p ) sendo assim a minha sugestão terceira sugestão indica uma tag pra resolver este problema.

Comment: Vejo que parece entender bem de R, tendo até medalha de bronze na tag, sendo assim peço que veja a minha opinião sobre o assunto "estatísticas": http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4727/3635 - Sua opinião pode ser importante.

Answer (score 4):

### Sugestão para assuntos referentes ao http://getbootstrap.com

Tornar a tag [bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) sinônimo de [twitter-bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap)

### Motivo:

- Esta sugestão é devido ao grande numero (~400 perguntas no site usaram pra se refereir ao http://getbootstrap.com) de perguntas que usou a tag [bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) se referindo a este assunto.
- E as para outros assuntos a tag [bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) foi usada raramente (2 perguntas apenas, até aonde encontrei dados).

Comment: Acho que não entenderam, comentar os negativos e sugerir alternativas é importante.

Comment: se calhar é melhor mesmo. Mas de qualquer forma devia-se alterar a wiki da tag e avisar.

Answer (score 4):

**Baseado na sugestão do [@Bacco](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4877/3635):**

Remover a tag bootstrap sem prefixo de todas perguntas e criar tags com prefixos pra cada situação (algumas já tem como twitter-bootstrap)

o SOen fez isto com algumas tags e parece que resolveu o problema, como por exemplo a tag `[composer]` no SOen é apenas um sinônimo pra tag de maior ocorrência (gerenciador de pacotes pra php) que ficou sendo:

- `composer-php`
- `visual-composer`
- `quartz-composer`
- `code-composer`

Isto é apenas um exemplo, no caso com o tempo criaríamos as tags, mas inicialmente "mataríamos" a tag bootstrap (talvez o @Gabe (ou alguém da staff) possa remover todas perguntas que usam a tag bootstrap de uma maneira mais rápida, como sugestão do @JorgeB.).

A tags poderiam ficar algo como:

- `twitter-bootstrap` (já existe)
- `bootstrap-r` (para o [r](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r))

E se houver mais usos analisar e criar as novas tags.

A única diferença da sugestão do @Bacco é que ao remover as tags bootstrap o sistema irá sozinho dar um fim nela, enviando ela para o "limbo" (o qual só moderadores tem acesso), claro que alguém pode recriar a tag, mas então eu já solicitei uma proposta (que tá demorado -.-):

- [Aumentar reputação necessária pra se criar tags](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5094/3635)

Comment: Não era melhor falar com o @Gabe sobre isso? É que mudar 400 perguntas é obra.

Comment: Ele deve conseguir fazer isso.

Comment: @JorgeB. sim ótima ideia =)

Comment: @JorgeB. Atualizei a resposta

Comment: Olha uma coisa, eu fui agora ver e são só 22 perguntas afinal...

Comment: @JorgeB. sim, é que geralmente eu edito as perguntas e removo todas tags bootstrap pra não causar confusão com `r` e `twitter-bootstrap`, por isso não acumulou, teve um dia que editei quase 20 perguntas hehehe... Por isso a minha preocupação pra resolver o que fazer com a tag =)

Comment: agora só com 22 resolvia-se fácil...

Answer (score 3):

### Sugestão sobre o pacote boot da linguagem R

Criar a tag [r-boot](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-boot), quando se referir ao pacote:

- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/boot/index.html

### Motivo

Uma das perguntas que usou a tag [bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) foi uma referencia a um problema no uso do pacote *boot*, então está tag deve ser usada apenas quando se tratar de duvidas ao usar o pacote citado sobre a linguagem [r](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r).

Comment: Por favor se for negativar comente o motivo da discordância, aqui é meta e não o site principal, aqui os votos são apenas para opiniões.

Comment: acho desnecessário compartilho do mesmo pensamento do @Daniel Falbel

Answer (score 3):

### Sugestão para perguntas de assuntos variados

Criar a tag [bootstrapping](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping) para situação:

### Motivo:

Um dos motivos é que no [*StackOverflow em inglês*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bootstrapping/info) estão usando está mesma tag (e parece ser bem aceita) para assuntos como:

> uma série de procedimentos que ocorre quando um aplicativo é iniciado ou um pedido através da web é recebido

E outro motivo é que lendo o Wikipédia (não estou afirmando que é o lugar mais confiável de informação :p) e lá pode-se notar o quão amplo é o uso do termo:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping

Comment: Por favor se for negativar comente o motivo da discordância, aqui é meta e não o site principal, aqui os votos são apenas para opiniões.

Comment: bootstrap já indica esse conceito

Answer (score 3):

### Sugestão para perguntas sobre estatísticas

Não devemos criar tags sobre o assunto *"estatísticas"*.

### Motivo:

Está é uma sugestão diferente das demais, ela fala para não criar pois a ideia é dizer o porque pode haver discordância quanto ao escopo do site, segue motivos do por que as tags [estatísticas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/estat%c3%adsticas) e [bootstrapping-estatísticas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping-estat%c3%adsticas) são dispensáveis:

- A linguagem R já é voltado a criação de softwares de estatísticas e ao usar a tag [r](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) já mostra de certa forma que estamos falando de *"da criação de software de estatísticas"*
- Mesmo não sendo sobre R, criar uma tag para estatísticas pode ser dispensável devido o problema geralmente ser no **algorítimo**, sendo que o problemas no código (sendo R ou não) podem ser estes:

  - de programação
  - de lógica
  - de compilação (ou interpretação, depende de como o software funciona)
  - de libs ou pacotes

  Então "estatísticas" é apenas o resultado desejado.

Answer (score 2):

### Sugestão para perguntas sobre estatísticas

Criar a tag [bootstrapping-estatísticas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping-estat%c3%adsticas)

### Motivos:

- A linguagem R é voltada desenvolver software de estatística e análise de dados e apesar de serem assuntos fora do escopo a principio, ainda sim tem surgido conteúdo relacionado. Como estástiticas não é algo apenas para R, mas pode ser feito em qualquer linguagem e por isto sugeri tal tag.
- O uso das tag [bootstrapping](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping) e [bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) para se referir as estatísticas pode conflitar em muito com outros assuntos que o "bootstrapping" abrange, veja:

  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)
  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping

Comment: Se discordar desta resposta por favor leia esta http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4730/3635 - Comente e de sua opinião, ela é importante ;)

Answer (score 0):

### Meio que uma *feature request*

O ideal seria que o site oferecesse a opção de criar "tags filhas", e que a seguinte regra fosse criada (e aplicada pelo próprio site), uma "tag filha" só poderá ser utilizada na presença de uma "tag pai", quando uma "tag filha" é utilizada na presença da "tag pai" ela terá um significado específico naquele contexto e também "linkará" a uma wiki específica para aquele assunto.

### Mas... como não temos isso, só nos resta um *workaround*

Já a funcionalidade especificada acima não existe no site, o que nós poderíamos fazer é o seguinte, permitir que uma tag possa ser utilizada para fazer referência a diversas coisas ao mesmo tempo, mas apenas quando forem utilizadas em conjunto com outras.

Ou seja, supondo que um usuário queria fazer uma pergunta sobre bootstrap, mas bootstrap no contexto da linguagem R, que se refere a um pacote que faz alguma coisa aí. Nesse caso o usuário teria que abrir a sua pergunta e colocar pelo menos as tags [r](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) e [bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap).

Agora um outro exemplo, supondo que um usuário queria fazer uma pergunta sobre bootstrap, mas bootstrap no contexto da linguagem CSS, que se refere ao um framework que faz umas outras coisas aí. Nesse caso o usuário teria que abrir a sua pergunta e colocar pelo menos as tags [css](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) e [bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap).

E sobre a wiki da tag? Bom, a wiki da tag bootstrap do exemplo acima poderia ser divida em secções e teria que conter informações sobre as duas tecnologias. Uma sugestão de formato para a wiki desse tipo de tag poderia ser o seguinte:

---

## [r](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) > [bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap)

[Algumas informações]

---

## [css](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) > [bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap)

[Outras informações]

---

Markdown do exemplo acima:

```
# [tag:r] > [tag:bootstrap]

[Algumas informações]

----

# [tag:CSS] > [tag:bootstrap]

[Outras informações]
```

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição, mas sendo assim não seria mais fácil apenas combinar tags? É que seguindo um fluxo de banco de dados tags filhas aumentaria extremamente a complexidade, tornando talvez esta solicitação de nova funcionalidade impossível. Sei que parece estranho o que disse. Mas até que faz sentido a sua resposta, só não sei a curto prazo :/ ... Talvez de inicio criar sinonimos pra evitar problemas e depois se um dia tal funcionalidade existir criar as tags filhas e remover os sinonimos.

Comment: Não era mais simples ter uma tag [tag:r-bootstrap] e outra [tag:bootstrap] ?

Comment: @JorgeB. concordo com você, pensei aqui agora e talvez o ideal seria fazer isso mesmo, criar [tag:r-bootstrap] e [tag:bootrap], pois assim a gente não afeta quem estiver filtrando as perguntas no site, como vocês devem saber é possível filtrar perguntas por tags, dessa forma que sugeri essa filtragem iria acabar ficando muito poluída, então voto pela criação dessas "tags com nomes compostos", tipo [tag:r-bootstrap].

Comment: Não negativei, pois sendo um "request feature" parece um bom caminho, no entanto gostaria que formulasse uma nova sugestão para uma solução a curto prazo ;)

Answer (score -3):

### Sugestão para perguntas sobre estatísticas

Criar a tag [estatísticas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/estat%c3%adsticas)

### Motivo:

Pelo mesmo motivo citado nesta sugestão: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4726/3635

> - A linguagem R é voltada desenvolver software de estatística e análise de dados e apesar de serem assuntos fora do escopo a principio, ainda sim tem surgido conteúdo relacionado. Como estástiticas não é algo apenas para R, mas pode ser feito em qualquer linguagem e por isto sugeri tal tag.
> - O uso das tag [bootstrapping](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping) e [bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) para se referir as estatísticas pode conflitar em muito com outros assuntos que o "bootstrapping" abrange, veja:
>
>   - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)
>   - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping

Comment: Se discordar desta resposta por favor leia esta http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4730/3635 - Comente e de sua opinião, ela é importante ;)