# Solicitação de remoção da tag foundation

Tags: suporte, tags

Recentemente realizei um esforço de edição na tag [zurb-foundation](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zurb-foundation) adicionando informações sobre a mesma. E vendo as perguntas relacionada a tag, me deparei com a tag [foundation](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foundation), da qual também não tem descrição.

E analisando a [tag no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/foundation/info), a mesma é confundida com um framework escrito em Objective-C.

Assim **solicito a remoção da tag** [foundation](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foundation), ja acessei todas as perguntas que utilizavam erroneamente e fiz a substituição/remoção, a não ser uma que acho que também deveria ser removida:

- [Qual linguagem corresponde a “Foundation”? [fechada]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102690/qual-linguagem-corresponde-a-foundation)

Comment: Precisa decidir o que fazer com com todas as que sobraram. Porque elas não deveriam ter esta tag?

Comment: Editei todas as perguntas que utilizavam erroneamente a tag (esqueci que atualizando a tag, as pergunta vão para o topo da timeline :/ ), porém uma usa corretamente, mas ainda acho valido remover dessa pergunta

Comment: Eu queria que sumissem e bloqueassem certas tags, principalmente a tag [tag:bootstrap], o qual acaba se misturando com no minimo 3 assuntos distintos. Mas realmente tem coisa que eu já desisti, eu removi já umas 3 vezes essa tag e adicionei as adequadas aos assuntos e não adianta sempre volta, eu já fiz uma postagem [aqui no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4718/3635) e o pessoal não se importa muito, realmente tenho poucas esperanças.