# Eliminar a tag da [stackexchange]?

Tags: debate, tags

Poderiam eliminar as tags da [stackexchange](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange) e [api-stackexchange](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api-stackexchange) por favor?

Vou citar alguns pontos que possam levar a considerarem à eliminação:

- Não há perguntas, nem usuários "ativos" - **último registro de 2014**;
- Propaganda no próprio site? Creio que seja desnecessário;
- Acho que já citei, mas vou citar denovo: **sem atividade desde 2014**;
- Eu fiz uma edição - muito tempo atrás - e foi rejeitada, dizendo que:

  > Esta tag não faz sentido nem de existir no site principal, talvez no meta.

A [edição comentada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/113126) no post.

Então que tal eliminar essas tags da stackexchange no site principal?

Comment: E se quisermos fazer perguntar sobre a API dos sites?

Comment: Dai acredito que teríamos que eliminar todas as tags que se referenciam a alguma API, tipo [tag:facebook], [tag:google], [tag:orkut] (:P)

Comment: Usa a tag API @LINQ

Comment: Acho que não precisa ser assim, foi mais pelo comentário da edição dizer que não faz sentido @MarceloBoni

Comment: Além disso essas são tag mais ativas

Comment: Não vejo nenhum motivo pra remover estas tags. O comentário da rejeição não está certo, provavelmente quem revisou não percebeu do que se tratam as tags.

Comment: Eu reijeitei, a edição não fazia sentido da forma que estava, achei desnecessária, só errei no motivo, realmente a tag pode existir, só o texto dela que ficou exagerado.

Comment: Só pra constar, entendo o porque você fez este wiki, até mesmo o texto da info tá errado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/stackexchange/info, ele também só fala da rede, tinha que falar também da API (já que tem tag de sinonimo), talvez isto tenha te levado ao erro, assim que possivel se quiser revisar ambos seria legal ;)

Comment: Pode deixar, quando tiver um tempo livre eu vejo se consigo melhorar alguns aspectos @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: Pensando aqui, pode ser o caso de manter apenas `api-stackexchange`.

Comment: Seria interessante, a tag [tag:stackexchange] não faz muito sentido, talvez transformar em sinônimo

Comment: @bfavaretto eu apoio essa decisão.

Comment: @UzmkArtanis não é possivel, isso não existe no sistema, se existisse muitos problemas teriam sido resolvidos já, veja esse: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4718/3635

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tags **são removidas automaticamente** (leva algum tempo) se não existirem perguntas que usem elas, se editar todas as perguntas e remover as tags em alguns dias o sistema remove elas.

Entenda que se existe tiver uma pergunta com a tag é porque é útil, não tem porque remover as tag destas perguntas existentes:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange

Eu mesmo usava esta API da Stack Exchange (usei inicialmente em um add-on próprio, hoje não mais) e se eu precisar usar novamente a API e então eu tiver uma duvida? O que faço? Terei que criar novamente a tag?

É que o pessoal não tem muito interesse, vou dizer poucos criam coisas com este proposito na comunidade em português e as coisas criadas geralmente não tem muita popularidade, dificilmente o publico do SOpt se interessa, mas 1% que seja de pessoas interessadas em usar e distribuir apps e add-ons já é o suficiente para que as tags sejam úteis.

### Sobre a rejeição no wiki da tag

A [**rejeição**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/113126) é um problema totalmente a parte sem relação com a tag, o motivo é outro, no caso o intuito das tags no site é passar mais orientação de onde e quando usar a tag e talvez links da documentação, ali o wiki deveria falar no minimo da API talvez e de outras coisas que podem ser usadas por desenvolveres relacionado a alguma tecnologia, mas **não** sobre *a rede SE*, se a tag fosse no Meta faria sentido, mas no site principal não, fora que o texto ficou esta mais para promover do que para explicar algo:

> Stack Exchange: A maior comunidade de programação do mundo está crescendo!

Comment: Entendi o que você falou. Só tinha aberto a pergunta devido à maneira do comentário da rejeição.

Comment: @UzmkArtanis sim, o comentário foi errado, mas isso é relativo, no entendimento do diegofm esta correto, a tag não deviria existir porque a descrição que você escreveu fazia entender que o uso da tag era sobre a rede SE, o que não tem sentido de uso no site SOpt. Então no geral ele agiu corretamente. Claro que ele não sabia da API da SE talvez.

Comment: Eu não rejeitei nada da tag API Guilherme, foi somente dessa. Só não concordo em terem tomado meu comentário como verdade absoluta, e como já foi explicado por mim e pela sua resposta que não era bem assim, me culpar pela sugestão da exclusões equivocado desta pergunta. Nenhum usuário é possuidor do conhecimento absoluto, dirá-se então no stackoverflow, com tantas mentes mais experientes e sábias que eu.

Comment: @diegofm acho que você entendeu errado o que eu disse :), eu não acusei ninguem, pelo contrário o que vc disse no ultimo paragrafo foi o mesmo que eu disse. Deixa eu te explicar de outra maneira....

Comment: Entendi, meu comentário foi mais uma réplica ao do OP, em justificar que a sugestão de exclusão partiu unicamente do meu comentário, como se me culpasse pela sugestão ter sido equivocada.

Comment: @diegofm não tem tag api, estou falando do uso da tag stackexchange para perguntas sobre a API da SE, o problema não era você e sim a descrição da tag original, veja que nem foi o Uzmk que criou esta descrição foi o Bruno: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/20858/revisions isso levou o Uzmk ao entendimento errado, então pelo "fragmento" (não falo do wiki) o seu entendimento Diego estava totalmente correto, a tag nem deveria existir, pelo menos não daquela maneira. Foi isso o que eu quis dizer, a sua lógica estava corretíssima :)

Comment: O bom de tudo de todo o problema aqui é que mesmo ocorrendo os desentendimentos nós encontramos um problema, a tag stackexchange precisa ser revisada, pois estava errada a muito tempo xD