# Vamos arrumar a tag bootstrap

Tags: debate, tags

[Cancelei agora uma contribuição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/137353) não por causa dela ser má mas porque a tag tem problemas.
<sub>([DvD](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/8063/dvd): as minhas desculpas)</sub>

Na verdade a tag [bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) tem problemas pois "bootstrap" é usado em situações diferentes. Isso [já foi apontado anteriormente aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4718/129).

Então vamos arrumar a tag uma vez por todas **\o/**

Podem dar sugestões de futuras tags (1 por resposta para podermos votar as ideias), e depois separamos tudo.

**Por exemplo:**

<sub>(vou dar exemplos toscos porque não me sinto muito inspirado)</sub>

- bootstrap-ui - para quando usamos no browser (css, jQuery)
- bootsrap-boot - para quando nos referimos aos arranque de uma página e tudo o que precisa ser carregado
- etc...

sugestões são bem-vindas!

Comment: O [tag:bootstrap-ui] não seria o mesmo do [tag:twitter-bootstrap]?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual deve ser o uso correto da tag "bootstrap"?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4718/qual-deve-ser-o-uso-correto-da-tag-bootstrap) ... debati isso durante 3 meses ano passado, mas houve muito pouco interesse da comunidade.

Comment: Acabei de encontrar a tag [tag:bootstrap-3]. Devemos então ter um [tag:bootsrap-ui-3] ou [tag:twitter-bootstrap-3]?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é, por isso coloquei o link da tua pergunta na minha. Para se rever as ideias lá geradas e resolvermos a coisa de vez.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado creio que `twitter-bootstrap` fazia sentido nas primeiras versões. Hoje acho que o `bootstrap` já não usa esse nome, já tem maturidade própria.

Comment: Eu deixaria `boostrap` para o CSS mesmo, dado o número de perguntas e mudaria a tag para os outros contextos, que são bem menos utilizados.

Comment: Então [tag:bootstrap] para a questão de UI, [tag:bootstrap-boot] para o processo de arranque?

Comment: Eu sugeriria apenas uma tag `bootstrap` para englobar tudo que for relacionado ao Bootstrap, separado apenas por versões importantes (?). Ex.: `bootstrap`, `bootstrap3`, `bootstrap4`... tal como acontece no HTML, onde tem as tags `html` e `html5`.

Comment: @DvD "bootstrap" tem outros sentidos para além do framework de CSS, e esta discussão é sobre isso, não sobre distinguir versões desse framework.

Comment: Ainda não entendo porque uma nova pergunta sendo que já existe uma.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é um complemento. A ideia é chamar a atenção para o problema, referir o trabalho que já tinhas feito e a boa explicação e resolver a coisa de vez. A tua pergunta já tem 2 anos, e as respostas não estão muito votadas. A minha ideia é tentar de novo envolver a comunidade na discussão.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado eu deixaria só "boot" pro processo, e "bootstrap-ui" (tem que ver o nome oficial) para a UI. O termo isolado "bootstrap" eu deixaria com um aviso de que não é pra usar ([vide o que postei na [pergunta linkada](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4718/129)) e apontando as alternativas (instrução de uso de desambiguação).

Comment: Relacionado: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125234/a-real-solution-to-ambiguous-tags @Bacco

Comment: @bfavaretto Gostaria muito de poder contribuir, mas como não sou muito inteirado em `bootstrap`, não me sinto confortável em dar opinião. Só espero que a questão seja resolvida da melhor forma para o bem da comunidade. Mas de qualquer forma vou ficar acompanhando. Sempre estou lendo sobre `bootstrap` e caso me surgir algo que eu ache que possa ser aproveitado, eu deixo a minha opinião ou comentário. Como eu sou uma pessoa pragmática, eu sempre tendo para as coisas mais simples rs :).

Comment: @bfavaretto gostei muito dessa [proposta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125234/246117) aí. É uma evolução natural da idéia.

Comment: @Sergio concordo que hoje em dia já seja um projeto independente, mas acho que era a melhor solução para este caso. No SOen está como twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3 e mais recentemente bootstrap-4. No caso de "bootstrap" com o sentido que está atualmente no SOen está referido como ["bootstraping"](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bootstrapping/info) que me parece a melhor opção.

Answer (score 7):

Concordo com duas das opções do @Guilherme Nascimento, não vou escrever de novo os motivos, vou apenas enunciar com link para a resposta correspondente.

[1.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4723/7210) Tornar a tag [bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) sinônimo de [twitter-bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) por razões de histórico;

[2.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4725/7210) Criar a tag [bootstrapping](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping) para a atual definição da tag [bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap);

3. Outras tags do género associar um prefixo ou sufixo especifico;

Comment: +1 pelos motivos já citados.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não faço a mínima ideia que sugestão de edição foi feita, mas creio que quem a fez tomou atenção que a [descrição atual da tag](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/bootstrap/info), não corresponde aquela que é usada nas perguntas.

Eu não acompanho muito perguntas de [css](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) nem de UI na web. Ainda assim creio que ao contrário do sugerido, não há muito valor em fragmentar as perguntas sobre a framework bootstrap.

A solução por mim proposta seria a mesma do @Jefferson Quesado. Use a tag [twitter-bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap). Além disso, seria interessante criar também a tag [bootstrapping](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping). Essa seria a tag com o mesmo significado que a tag [bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) tem hoje (embora esse significado não esteja a ser respeitado).

Seria também pertinente analisar erros ortográficos em perguntas existentes quando a tag foi usada. Por exemplo [esta pergunta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/242507/) usa a tag [boostrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boostrap).

Em relação à tag [bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) acho que se possa criar um sinónimo com [bootstrapping](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping), contudo [bootstrapping](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping) seria a tag principal.

Comment: bootstrap e bootstraping pode ser algo muito ambíguo mesmo não falando sobre o tal framework front-end. Pode ser desenvolvimento, instalação, compilação, estatísticas. Não acho que o termo esteja de fato sendo usado errado, o termo simplesmente é ambíguo, logo a culpa não é das pessoas o usarem assim. Outras sugestões em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4718/3635

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu só estava interessado em resolver o problema do [tag:twitter-bootstrap]. Nada mais. Daí ter sugerido a tag [tag:bootstrapping] ela é diferente o suficiente para nao ser confudida com a mesma coisa.

Comment: Entendo, faz sentido mesmo Bruno Costa

Comment: Desde esse [comentário do Sérgio](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6472/vamos-arrumar-a-tag-bootstrap#comment25059_6472) eu retirei a ideia do `twitter-bootstrap` pelos motivos citados lá ;-) (mesmo que não tenha removido o comentário, a ideia eu removi da minha cabeça e propus outra coisa em outro comentário)

Comment: A pergunta citada com [tag:boostrap] já editei para apontar para [tag:bootstrap-3], já que se tratava dessa versão do framework